# Javascript getElementsByName not working in PHP loop

Tags: javascript, php, loops, getelementsbyname

I've the following **PHP code** :

```
//some code
$query = "SELECT * from store_00_transfers";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo "<tr><td align=center width=19%>{$row['item_no']}</td><td align=center><input type='text' value='{$row['qty']}' name='cqty[]' readonly ></td><td align=center><input type='number' min='0' name='nqty[]' onChange='check_not_large(this.value);' value='0'></td></tr>";        

}

//rest of code
```

Now, as you can see there is a function inside `onChange`. That function is meant to check whether the number inserted by user for new qty should not exceed old qty (I use this method to transfer qty's from one store to another).

Please also note I've assigned a name `cqty[]` and `nqty[]` inside input fields.

I have **javascript code** :

```
<script>
function check_not_large(res) {

  var old = document.getElementsByName("cqty[]");
  var type= document.getElementsByName("nqty[]");
  for(var i = 0; i < old.length; i++) {
    if(type[i].value > old[i].value){

      alert('Error : Qty Inserted should be Less than QTY found in Store !');
      alert(type[i].value);
      alert(old[i].value);
      return type[i].value = 0;

    }

  }
}

</script>
```

I've used *`alert` in javascript* to test if correct values are collected and it seems that it works as needed, but NOT for validating if new qty is more than old qty, it seems that it works only for the first 4 rows then it stucks and starts validating the new qty in any row WITH the first old qty row .. I hope this makes sense to you.

Any alternative or suggestion will be appreciate it.

Thanks Guy

Comment: what is `name='cqty[]'` why you are using such type of name havig array sign??

Comment: without this array sign I'm getting javascript error using alert - object nodelist or undefined . I'm not so familiar with JS. As I've mentioned earlier its inside `while loop`, so `name` will be repeated many time.

Comment: You've got a typo in your html "</td</tr>""

Comment: Instead of using alerts, you should look into the debugging console, which is way more flexible than alerts. Eg for Google chrome see this page : https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: can someone explain -1 for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is that everytime you input value onto nqty and on onchange, the function check_not_large function gets called and it not only validating  current row nqty and cqty  values but also all the previous nqty and cqty row values.If your purpose is to check only if current row nqty value greater than cqty value, a much neater code will be to give some unique id value to each nqty and cqty elements.The code for the same can be optimized as given below.

PHP Code

```
$query = "SELECT * from store_00_transfers";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<tr>
        <td align=center width=19%>{$row['item_no']}</td>
          <td align=center>
             //instead of name attribute you can give an id here and also assuming $row['item_no'] is unique
             <input type='text' value='{$row['qty']}'    id='cqty{$row['item_no']}' readonly >//assuming item_no is unique
         </td>
         <td align=center>
           //instead of name attribute you can give an id here and also  assuming $row['item_no'] is unique
           <input type='number' min='0' id="nqty{$row['item_no']}"    onChange='check_not_large({$row['item_no']});' value='0'>
        </td>
        </tr>";
```

}

Javascript Code

```
<script>
    function check_not_large(item_no) {
       var cqtvVal=document.getElementById("cqtv"+item_no).value;
       var nqtvVal=document.getElementById("nqtv"+item_no).value;
       //checking if typed value is greater than old value
       if(nqtvVal>cqtvVal)
       {
         //write whatever code you want to do like give a warning message or make the nqtv value reset to zero etc
       }   

   }
 </script>
```

Comment: I understand your code, assigning id would help out but the problem that item_no is not unique. I have id ( in table structure ) and I have used it but it seems that it fails to give me any alert. I'll double check again. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Ok if it were so then put a count variable inside the php while loop which holds the current iteration value.Use this count variable instead of item_no or use the current row number.

Comment: Ok let me try it right now and i'll let you know. Thanks again

Comment: Also please check in browser how the html code is generated.

Comment: Did you get your issue resolved?.Always check the generated html code to find out everything is working as expected.

Comment: It took a lot of time to figure out what causing the error, and I realized that when changing input type from `number` to `text` works as needed. I really don't understand why, but that's what was causing this annoying issue. :/

Comment: document.getElementById("myNumber").value will get you the value from the number field.

Comment: Yea I've tried that but when you use up arrow to increment number it returns back the alert error..But when you type down any number it works without problem . Anyways Thanks for your care, I've +1 and correct answer aimed for you :)

Comment: Thanks..happy to help :)